# align text line so its center will be 70% of the container width

Tags: css

I would like to align string a text, so that the center of that string will be at the pixel that is 70% of the container width. Apart from that string, all the other text lines in the container is normally (left) aligned.
e.g if the container width is 300px, the center of the text is at pixel 210.

What is the best way to accomplish that?
Is there a way to do it if it shares the line with more normally (left) aligned text?

UPDATE: 
I'm afraid i was unclear with my question. Applogies to all who took the time to answer. 
To be clearer, the container contains many lines of text, all normally (left) aligned. There is just one string that i want to position so its center is at 70% of the container width.

Comment: have you tried anything , like padding or else ?

Answer (score 1):

This may help. 
Change the width in the `::before` accordingly. Let the container take its parent's width.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
  Text
</div>

// CSS
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.container::before {
  content: '';
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/gokulkaripath/pen/zzKmVN)

Hope this helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can fake this alignment by placing your text in an inner span inside your container and position that span accordingly

on the container:

```
position: relative;
```

on the inner span:

```
  position: absolute;
  left: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```

see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/michabeeri/tmyebqh8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```css
#thediv {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <center>
    <div id="thediv">
    text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```